# Can Kai Chisaki fuse with anyone?

Tags: my-hero-academia

IIRC Kai Chisaki was just introduced in the last episode of the anime. I havent read the manga, but in one My Hero Academia wikia they state Kai Chisaki fused with another villain. How does this work? Can he fuse only with people who wants to fuse or could he fuse with anyone, for example, Midoriya and obtaining One for All by exerting his powers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

His quirk allows him to shape matter to his own extent just by touching the area. He touches the other person's body and it explodes than it comes back and merges into his own. He all he needs to do this is to get the hands on the said person.